# using XmlNamespaceManager for retrieving list of all namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to get list of all defined namespaces by `XmlNamespaceManager` in this code:

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
var dic = manager.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
```

and this is my xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<psf:PrintCapabilities 
 version='1' 
 xmlns:psf='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework' 
 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
 xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
 xmlns:ns0000='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/printing/oemdriverpt/Lexmark T650/6.1.7601.17514/' 
 xmlns:psk='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords'>

 </psf:PrintCapabilities>
```

Interestingly GetNamespacesInScope() method returns **only one item** (*key="xml", value="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"*)

What is missing here?

Note: even if I use one of the defined namespace prefixes (for example by adding `<ns0000:a>hi</ns0000:a>`) it does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using XPathDocument as well as XmlNamespaceScope... Something like this will work

```
 XPathDocument x = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
 XPathNavigator foo = x.CreateNavigator();
 foo.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
 IDictionary<string, string> namespaces = foo.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that those are not namespaces, those are namespace declarations.

If you actually *used* those namespaces, then they would exist as the namespace on the nodes in the name table, so XmlNamespaceManager would show them to you. As it is, it only shows the `xml` namespace, which is implicitly present on all XML documents.